# JS - Smooth scroll down page to particular element

Tags: javascript, html, forms

To start, I'm quite new to coding, especially JavaScript. I'm currently making a website with two forms one at the top of the page and one at the bottom.

I want two things to happen when I submit the top form:

- the value of the input of the top form gets transferred to the input in the bottom form (I have this figured out)
- smooth scroll from the top form to the bottom form (what I need help figuring out)

I've tried using .scrollTop and other solutions I've found around the internet and on random forums, but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions are welcome. I'd prefer to keep this website quite light and don't really want to add any jQuery plugins or anything of that kind.

With this code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#top-email').val();
        $('#bot-email').val(email);
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="transferEmail.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="top-form">
            <input type="text" id="top-email">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
    </div>
    <div>
        <form>
            <input id="bot-email">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

html {
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    background: blue;
    padding: 5%;
}

.spacer {
    height: 1500px;
    background: green;
}

input {
    width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: In future questions, try to refine the post to just what is relevant. You say you've figured out the move value from one form to another and really just need help with the scroll part, so that should be the title of your question.

Comment: ScollTo should work, if you know the position of your 2nd form. You can also try to set focus on the 2nd form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#top-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#top-email').val();
    $('#bot-email').val(email);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#bot-email").offset().top}, 2000);
 });
});
```

You can try this.

Comment: Got it to work, had to change the srollTop to the id of the form instead of the input, but it worked. Thanks a ton.